# Ruby on Rails session[:user_id] not being set properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session

I Created a login controller where once a user is logged in, he will be directed to his home page. As shown below, I'm setting the session variable in the login controller. In the application controller I have current user methods which will check whether a user exists for the currently logged in key. Although I log in successfully, If i use later the 'current_user method' given in ApplicationController, It redirects me to the login page as the current_user is a nil object. Does any one have any idea as to where I went wrong.

```
class User::Signin::LoginController < ApplicationController

def login
render('/login')
end

def attempt_login
    @user = User.find_by_email(params[:user][:email])
    if @user && @user.authenticate(params[:user][:password])
      session[:user_id] = @user.id
      flash[:notice] = "You are now logged in"


      if @user.role == 1

        redirect_to controller: '/patient/home', action: 'show', :id => @user.patient_id
      end

      if @user.role ==2
        redirect_to controller: '/doctor/home', action: 'show', :id => @user.doctor_id
      end

      if @user.role ==3
        redirect_to controller: '/staff/home', action: 'show', :id => @user.staff_id
      end


    else
      flash.now[:notice] = "Invalid username/ password combination."
      render 'login/login'
    end
  end

 def logout
    session[:user_id] = nil
    flash[:notice] = 'logged out'
    redirect_to('/login')
  end

end
```

The ApplicationController

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  helper_method :current_user

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_id!(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end

  def require_user
    redirect_to '/login' unless current_user
  end

  def require_admin
    redirect_to '/login' unless current_user.admin?
  end

  def require_doctor
    redirect_to '/login' unless current_user.doctor?
  end

  def require_patient
    redirect_to '/login' unless current_user.patient?
  end

  def require_staff
    redirect_to '/login' unless current_user.staff?
  end

  private
  def confrim_logged_in
    unless session[:user_id]
      flash[:notice] = "Please log in"
      redirect_to '/login'
    end
  end


end
```

Usage of current_user

```
class Patient::HomeController < ApplicationController
  layout 'patient'
  protect_from_forgery

  def show
    @patient = Patient.find(params[:id])
    @current_user=current_user
    render('patients/home')
  end


end
```

Comment: I believe it's because you assign the `@user` instance variable and the reference it when assigning your session as `user`

Comment: @BaylorRae' that was a error by mistake. I anyway had the @ sign with the 'user'. I corrected the code now. Can you please check and suggest whats wrong with it. Thanks in advance

Comment: Try removing the puts in your current_user method. Ruby returns the last line of a method

Comment: @BaylorRae' Hi thats aldo not the issue. Its like the session is never set. :( I'm going crazy trying to figure this out

Comment: protect_from_forgery with: :null_session & 
protect_from_forgery with: :exception ----- >
would these cause the session to not be set?

Comment: I corrected it by using :session instead of :user( [:session][:email]) in the attempt_login method. and it solved. thank you so much for your help too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to correct the error by changing from params[:user][:email] to params[:session][:email]. Doing this would cause me to change the view variables accordingly too.

```
def attempt_login
    @user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email])
    if @user && @user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      session[:user_id] = @user.id
      flash[:notice] = "You are now logged in"

//other code//

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below example, hope this helps

```
def attempt_login
        user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
        if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
            session[:user_id]=user.id
            flash[:success]="Logged in Successfully "

//ROLE CONDITIONS 

        else

            flash.now[:danger]="Email/Password is not matching"
            render'login/login'
        end
    end
```

Comment: So where are we instantiating the 'user' variable? I get the below error when I try your way.

undefined local variable or method `user' for #<User::Signin::LoginController:0x000000043d3548>

Comment: Heyy just changed the code please do check. It should work now @Awesomeness

Comment: Its still not working :/ protect_from_forgery with: :null_session & protect_from_forgery with: :exception ----- > would these cause the session to not be set?

Comment: No error. Its just not setting the session. It gets redirected to the home page after the login is successful

Comment: I corrected it by using :session instead of :user( [:session][:email]) in the attempt_login method. and it solved. thank you so much for your help too!

Comment: Dats great @awesomeness